# How is WP_Query parsed to determine which template to request?

Tags: wp-query, page-template

I noticed that when I changed the WP_Query to ask for a certain category, the page served was `category.php`. So I'm guessing there's a block of code somewhere that decides which template to serve based on keys in the query. Where is it?

Comment: @t31os please move that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [template](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/template-loader.php) loader determines which template to load for a given view, there's a filter available to change this though, `template_include` as seen on the source page linked.

Moved from comment to answer.